# Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded in angular 2

Tags: angular

In my angular2 project I have used compiler service to make a dynamic module and render it at runtime in the app. Issue is that when I run the command ng build --prod, it completed process without any error but after hosting it to the herokuapp If I run my app , it gives me error like,

```
core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:15714
```

ERROR 
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded

```
at t.rd (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:16852)
at e.<anonymous> (pdf-load.component.ts:69)
at tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:97
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:78)
at tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:71
at new t (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:910)
at Object.u (tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:67)
at e._next (pdf-load.component.ts:55)
at e.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:196)
at e.next (Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:134)
at P (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:831)
at new t (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:913)
at Object.u (tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:67)
at e._next (pdf-load.component.ts:55)
at e.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:196)
at e.next (Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:134)
at e._next (Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:77)
at e.next (Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:54)
at e._next (map.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:41)
at e.next (Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:54)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I think ng build is working fine if I am not wrong.?

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku uses `postinstall` and `preinstall` hooks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) which you can use to build:

```
"preinstall": "npm install -g http-server",
"postinstall": "ng build --prod"
```

You can also use the "start" hook to serve:

`"start": "http-server dist/"`

If anyone needs to deploy to heroku, pls, read this article first:
https://m.alphasights.com/using-nginx-on-heroku-to-serve-single-page-apps-and-avoid-cors-5d013b171a45#.drmqhuard

Use this build pack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static

And this static.json:

```
{
  "root": "dist/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```